# ksoap2 generating duplicate tags

Tags: android, ksoap2, duplicates

I'm having problems with the ksoap2 library on Android when I try to make a request.

After I created my request objects and when I make the http call, some of the objects are being duplicated and are assigned the value null. This of course gives me problems because the service responds that the object shouldn't be null.

Using fiddler I found out where the problem is.
The relevant part of my coding would look like this:

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = false;
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
    SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    soapEnvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,"request",new client_request().getClass());
    MarshalFloat marshalFloat = new MarshalFloat();
    marshalFloat.register(soapEnvelope);
    soapReq.addProperty("request",request);
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url,timeOut);
    soapEnvelope.headerOut= new Element[]{get_header()};
    try{
        if (headers!=null){
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope,headers);
        }else{
             httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope); }
    }
```

The relevant xml tags posted by my call are these:

```
<owner i:type="d:anyType">
            <person_type i:type="d:string">sometext</person_type>
</owner>
<owner i:null="true" />
<duration i:type="d:int">6</duration>
<duration i:null="true" />
<duration i:null="true" />
```

How can I get rid of these tags:

```
<owner i:null="true" />
<duration i:null="true" />
<duration i:null="true" />
```

I'm using Ksoap2 3.4.0 version and used a wsdl client generator.
If anybody can help me it would be much appreciated, i'm really out of ideas. I can add more info's if it's needed.

UPDATE:
So here is my client request class and the content of the request:

```
public class client_request implements KvmSerializable {

    public autentificare_sas autentificare_sas;
    public String societate;
    public vehicul vehicul;
    public owner owner;
    //public owner utilizator;
    public String clasa_bm_anterioara;
    public reduceri reduceri;
    public majorari majorari;
    public String data_inceput;
    public int durata;
  /*  public boolean generare_oferta;
    public boolean generare_ofertaSpecified;*/

    public client_request(){}

    public client_request(SoapObject soapObject)
    {
        if (soapObject == null)
            return;
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("autentificare_sas"))
        {
            SoapObject j = (SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("autentificare_sas");
            autentificare_sas =  new autentificare_sas (j);

        }
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("societate"))
        {
            Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("societate");
            if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
                SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
                societate = j.toString();
            }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof String){
                societate = (String) obj;
            }
        }
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("vehicul"))
        {
            SoapObject j = (SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("vehicul");
            vehicul =  new vehicul (j);

        }
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("owner"))
        {
            SoapObject j = (SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("owner");
            owner =  new owner (j);

        }
/*        if (soapObject.hasProperty("utilizator"))
        {
            SoapObject j = (SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("utilizator");
            utilizator =  new owner (j);

        }*/
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("clasa_bm_anterioara"))
        {
            Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("clasa_bm_anterioara");
            if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
                SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
                clasa_bm_anterioara = j.toString();
            }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof String){
                clasa_bm_anterioara = (String) obj;
            }
        }
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("reduceri"))
        {
            SoapObject j = (SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("reduceri");
            reduceri =  new reduceri (j);

        }
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("majorari"))
        {
            SoapObject j = (SoapObject)soapObject.getProperty("majorari");
            majorari =  new majorari (j);

        }
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("data_inceput"))
        {
            Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("data_inceput");
            if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
                SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
                data_inceput = j.toString();
            }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof String){
                data_inceput = (String) obj;
            }
        }
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("durata"))
        {
            Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("durata");
            if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
                SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
                durata = Integer.parseInt(j.toString());
            }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof Number){
                durata = (Integer) obj;
            }
        }
/*        if (soapObject.hasProperty("generare_oferta"))
        {
            Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("generare_oferta");
            if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
                SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
                generare_oferta = Boolean.parseBoolean(j.toString());
            }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof Boolean){
                generare_oferta = (Boolean) obj;
            }
        }
        if (soapObject.hasProperty("generare_ofertaSpecified"))
        {
            Object obj = soapObject.getProperty("generare_ofertaSpecified");
            if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)){
                SoapPrimitive j =(SoapPrimitive) obj;
                generare_ofertaSpecified = Boolean.parseBoolean(j.toString());
            }else if (obj!= null && obj instanceof Boolean){
                generare_ofertaSpecified = (Boolean) obj;
            }
        }*/
    }
    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        switch(arg0){
            case 0:
                return autentificare_sas;
            case 1:
                return societate;
            case 2:
                return vehicul;
            case 3:
                return owner;
/*            case 4:
                return utilizator;*/
            case 5:
                return clasa_bm_anterioara;
            case 6:
                return reduceri;
            case 7:
                return majorari;
            case 8:
                return data_inceput;
            case 9:
                return durata;
/*            case 10:
                return generare_oferta;
            case 11:
                return generare_ofertaSpecified;*/
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 12;
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                info.type = autentificare_sas.class;
                info.name = "autentificare_sas";
                break;
            case 1:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                info.name = "societate";
                break;
            case 2:
                info.type = vehicul.class;
                info.name = "vehicul";
                break;
            case 3:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
                info.name = "owner";
                break;
/*            case 4:
                info.type = owner.class;
                info.name = "utilizator";
                break;*/
            case 5:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                info.name = "clasa_bm_anterioara";
                break;
            case 6:
                info.type = reduceri.class;
                info.name = "reduceri";
                break;
            case 7:
                info.type = majorari.class;
                info.name = "majorari";
                break;
            case 8:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                info.name = "data_inceput";
                break;
            case 9:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                info.name = "durata";
                break;
/*            case 10:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS;
                info.name = "generare_oferta";
                break;
            case 11:
                info.type = PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS;
                info.name = "generare_ofertaSpecified";
                break;*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getInnerText() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInnerText(String s) {

    }

}

public void buildClientRequest(){

    client_request myRequest = new client_request();
    myRequest.durata = 6;
    myRequest.data_inceput = "2014-12-01";
    myRequest.clasa_bm_anterioara = "B0";
    myRequest.vehicul = buildVehicul();
    myRequest.owner = buildOwner();
    myRequest.societate = "XXXXXX";

    client_response myCLientResp = myInstance.get_client(myRequest);

}

 public vehicul buildVehicul(){

        vehicul myVehicul = new vehicul();

        myVehicul.numar_inmatriculare = "XX-99-YYY";
        myVehicul.tip_inmatriculare = WS_Enums.tipuri_inmatriculare.inmatriculat;
        myVehicul.serie_sasiu = "WSDF123123154";
        myVehicul.categorie = 1;
        myVehicul.subcategorie = "Autoturism de teren";
        myVehicul.marca = "XXXXX";
        myVehicul.model = "YYYYYYYY";
        myVehicul.an_fabricatie = 2005;
        myVehicul.capacitate_cilindrica = 1461;
        myVehicul.putere = 63;
        myVehicul.masa_maxima = 1065;
        myVehicul.numar_locuri = 5;
        myVehicul.combustibil = WS_Enums.tipuri_combustibili.benzina;
        myVehicul.tip_utilizare = WS_Enums.tipuri_utilizare.personal;
        myVehicul.carte_identitate = "H123123";

        return myVehicul;

    }

    public owner buildOwner(){

        owner myOwner = new owner();
        myOwner.tip_persoana = WS_Enums.tip_persoana.fizica;
        myOwner.cod_unic = "12345678912345";
        myOwner.nume = "XXXXX";
        myOwner.prenume = "YYYYY";
        myOwner.societate = null;
        myOwner.adresa = buildAdresa();
        myOwner.data_permis_conducere = "2012-02-29";
        myOwner.bugetar = true;
        myOwner.numar_daune = 3;
        myOwner.societate_de_leasing = false;
        myOwner.domeniu_activitate = 3;
        myOwner.categorie_pj = WS_Enums.categorie_pj.regiiautonome;

        return myOwner;

    }

    public adresa buildAdresa(){

        adresa myAdresa = new adresa();

        myAdresa.localitate_siruta = 999999;
        myAdresa.judet = "CJ";
        myAdresa.strada = "Principala";

        return myAdresa;

    }
```

I added only the methods which build the request, I hope it's ok like this.
After i call this:

```
client_response myCLientResp = myInstance.get_client(myRequest);
```

I get to the part that I showed before, where the envelope is created and the call is being made.

I thought that a problem could be the type of the owner:

```
            info.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
            info.name = "owner";
```

this is why I put PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS but this didn't solved anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think You may include client_request class and what is in variable "request".

Comment: Thanks man for the answer, I updated my question with the client_request code and the request.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

The problem was that in my request, I commented out two elements and instead of those elements empty tags where created using of course the last instance.

```
 @Override 
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch(index){
            case 0: 
                info.type = autentificare_sas.class;
                info.name = "autentificare_sas";
                break; 
            case 1: 
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                info.name = "societate";
                break; 
            case 2: 
                info.type = vehicul.class;
                info.name = "vehicul";
                break; 
            case 3: 
                info.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
                info.name = "owner";
                break; 
/*            case 4: 
                info.type = owner.class; 
                info.name = "utilizator"; 
                break;*/ 
            case 5: 
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                info.name = "clasa_bm_anterioara";
                break; 
            case 6: 
                info.type = reduceri.class;
                info.name = "reduceri";
                break; 
            case 7: 
                info.type = majorari.class;
                info.name = "majorari";
                break; 
            case 8: 
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                info.name = "data_inceput";
                break; 
            case 9: 
                info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                info.name = "durata";
                break; 
/*            case 10: 
                info.type = PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS; 
                info.name = "generare_oferta"; 
                break; 
            case 11: 
                info.type = PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS; 
                info.name = "generare_ofertaSpecified"; 
                break;*/ 
        } 
    }
```

So for those who have the same problem, pay attention to what you comment out from the request :-).

Cheers